# Can a C++ program run on Mac OS?

Tags: c++, macos

I have watched a video in which one of the director of scs software (who makes a EURO TRUCK SIMULATOR game) saying that the game is written entirely in C++, yet the game runs on Windows and Mac OS as well. How could they achieve it? Is it possible to run a C++ program on MAC OS?

Comment: The code that runs on the Mac isn't exactly the same as the code that runs on Windows, parts of the program are platform-specific. The program is of course compiled for each platform separately.

Comment: You can almost write programs in any programming language on any platform... The trick is to get the right compiler for it (and the libraries if needed).

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

...OK, stack overflow wants at least 30 characters. OS X comes with the C++ compiler `clang++`, which is built on top of `llvm`. In fact, Apple stopped supplying a port of `gcc` some time ago, so developers either have to build it themselves or adapt to `clang`. According to Wikipedia, Apple itself develops `clang`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, either to run gcc in terminal or to use Xcode to compile it, however you cannot then use Cocoa but alternatives such as Qt are available for mac.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there are C++ compilers for Mac OS X as well. One is even included in xcode (the standard development environment on a Mac).

But that does not mean, that you can compile just any C++ program on a Mac. It has to be designed to use libraries, that are available on both platforms (instead of MFC on Windows or Cocoa on the Mac). This is possible for example by using wxwidgets or QT. With these two libraries it is even possible to compile the program for Unix platforms like Linux as well.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of language a multi-platform program relies on some basic support parts that are implemented differently on each platform. With pure standard C++ this is the standard library and the runtime support, but in practice a game, say, will also rely on 3<sup>rd</sup> party libraries with platform specific implementations. So given that the platform itself is compatible with the basic platform assumptions of the C++ language, and the Mac is, achieving such portability is conceptually very straightforward, although difficult to get perfect.

As an example of a platform that's not entirely compatible with C++, Microsoft's .NET virtual machine is apparently so at odds with the ideas of C++ that Microsoft has found it necessary to define two different non-standard variants of C++ for it, and offers no way to produce GUI programs for it in pure standard C++. It's not *impossible* to use only standard C++ for .NET, and indeed one main reason to use C++ with .NET is to combine standard C++ parts with more .NET-y parts; it's just that using only standard C++ the code becomes complex, inefficient and generally impractical. For example, my first questions here on SO concerned how to do a simple .NET message box in standard C++ by way of COM technology as an intermediate layer, and that worked, but with a ridiculous amount of complex non-general support code.

As another example, using C++ in web pages is very much an impedance mismatch, so to speak. Again Microsoft is the main player who has attempted this, with their ActiveX technology. It turned out to be a good way ensure that PCs all over the world got infested with malware, because C++ is not the kind of language where it's easy to constrain what the code can do. As far as I know only Microsoft's own Internet Explorer browser ever supported ActiveX in web pages. And as of Windows 10 the IE browser is being phased out and replaced by the newer Edge browser, that does not support ActiveX in web pages.

Comment: C++ with emscripten and web assembly is cool concept, you should check it out. Nice sandboxing of cpp code in a browser.